# Optimizing SQL query that measures date difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running an SQL SELECT query that potentially could retrieve thousands and tens of thousands of records.
I will keep it concise: I need to get only records whose timestamp does not exceed 30 days ago.
I currently have 2 queries. One obviously faster than the other, and I'd like to know if it could be further optimized.
Useful information:
Example of how the timestamp looks: 2020-03-30-08_50_26_608156
I can NOT change this format.
faster query:

```
select * from someStatusTable
where 1=1
and getdate()-convert(datetime,left(FN_TIME_STAMP,10),121) < 30
```

Absolute trash query:

```
select  * from someStatusTable
where 1=1
and DATEDIFF(day, FORMAT (convert(datetime,  stuff(FN_TIME_STAMP, 11, 99, ''), 127), 'yyyy/MM/dd'),FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd')) < 30
```

Would you say the "faster" query is good enough? Is there any wise tricks to further optimize this?

Comment: You need to use the variable instead of  format function in where clause because the query can't use index

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand, you're referring to the "fast query" ? What do you mean by variable? I didn't use a variable here I think at least. These queries work, I'm just worried about performance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added tag - sql server (mssql)

Comment: @Krazy_Tech I understand what you meant now after Gordon Linoff's answer. thanks

Comment: Why are you using a string to compare values?

Comment: I inherited this table. I work for an enterprise thats kinda bad at this stuff. Its too widely used in the organization to make a change at this point. It could be done but its a long painful process which ill get to eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use:

```
select *
from someStatusTable
where FN_TIME_STAMP >= convert(date, dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
```

(I think that is the logic.)

This allows the database to use an index on `(FN_TIME_STAMP)`.  It helps the optimizer in general because there are no function calls on the column to obfuscate the statistics.

EDIT:

You have a bastardized time stamp because it is stored as a string.  I would suggest:

```
where FN_TIME_STAMP >= convert(varchar(10), dateadd(day, -30, getdate()), 23)
```

This can use an index on `(FN_TIME_STAMP)`.  It doesn't consider the time component of the date, but I'm guessing that is okay.

Comment: Is it better due to directly comparing FN_TIME_STAMP rather than comparing the numbers generated ? I'd also add that this query gives the error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." I guess the format isn't good for this?

Comment: @adame21 . . . The data should really be fixed so timestamps are stored using native data types -- that is, not as a string.  But I adjusted the answer for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the continuous help. Its not throwing an error now but I'm not getting any results while the other queries do give, I think the logic isnt 100% there. I will try to understand myself from here, but I won't resist help :)

Comment: So I looked a bit more into it. I realized "convert(varchar(11), dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))" returns something that looks like this: "Mar 29 2020" which doesent compare to FN_TIME_STAMP it seems...